# linux policy routing; Sending arp for off network IPs instead of sending traffic to gateway

Tags: routing, iproute, vlan

I'm in need of some assistance troubleshooting a policy routing issue.

I have a linux host with multiple VLANs. I'm trying to create a unique routing table for each VLAN and I can ping bidirectionally between the host and the router on VLAN20, however, on the upstream router I'm seeing ARP requests for remote IPs instead of ARP requests for the gateway or traffic being sent to the gateway from the Linux host.

Linux Host VLAN20: 192.168.20.50

Router interface VLAN20: 192.168.20.1

**Created the table "vlan20**"

```
$ cat /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
```

#
 # reserved values

#
255     local

254     main

253     default

220     vlan20

0       unspec
#

#local

## 1inr.ruhep

**Created rule to send all traffic sourced from VLAN20 interface using table vlan20**

```
$ ip rule show
```

0:      from all lookup local

32765:  from all iif eth0.20 lookup vlan20

32766:  from all lookup main

32767:  from all lookup default

**routing all traffic to the router vlan20 interfac**e

```
$ ip route list table vlan20
```

default via 192.168.20.1 dev eth0.20

**testing from linux host**

```
ping 8.8.8.8 -I eth0.20
```

PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) from 192.168.20.50 eth0.20: 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.20.50 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

**From Router VLAN20 interface**

9.568940 arp who-has 8.8.8.8 tell 192.168.20.50

10.565495 arp who-has 8.8.8.8 tell 192.168.20.50

Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

I guess a clash with the default host route is in question here. Assuming your linux host interface is eth0 and the host network is `10.77.0.0/24`, run this command:

`$ sudo ip route add 10.77.0.0/24 via 192.168.20.1 dev eth0.20 table vlan20
$ sudo ip rule add to 192.168.20.0/24 lookup vlan20 prio 10000`

to avoid the loop you are seeing. I still can not post comments and since my previous answer was deleted (it was really a question not an answer) I would also say that the output of `ip -4 addr show` and `ip route show` should had been provided so we can see the netmasks too and the routing details.